# Is it possible to make Search Results transparent?

Tags: 20.04, gnome, gnome-shell

**My system:**

- Distribution➜ UBUNTU 20.04.2 (LTS).
- GNOME Shell version➜ 3.36.8 (X11).

**Description of the question:**

In this picture, which mimics my actual display, the opacity of the Search Results is high:

[image: this picture]

I would like those results to be shown totally transparent:

[image: this other picture]

---

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider using another [flavor](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours). GNOME is developed to prioritize consistency and ease-of-use instead of providing lots of options for user customizations. If you want to fine tune your desktop environment in a meticulous way, GNOME is not a good choice of DE.

Comment: My customization wasn't easy to do, but I was able to tweak GNOME as I wanted to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I follow this steps to make it possible:

1. Search for `gnome-shell.css` inside the `gnome-shell` folder of your favorite theme... or the default one, too.
2. Open the CMD and login as SuperUser.
3. Type `nano` and drag the `gnome-shell.css` file to the CMD; hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Open the search tool using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>.
5. Type `search-section-separator`; hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
6. Replace the default *px* value of `height` for `1px` and the `background-color` value from `transparent` to `rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.16)`.
7. Go to `search-section-content`... it's just a few lines down or to the right side of `search-section-separator`.
8. In `background-color`, erase the *rgba* value [Example: rgba(42, 42, 42, 0.775)]  and replace it with `transparent` instead.
9. Change the *px* default values in `border-shadow` and `border` to `0px`.
10. Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to finish the transformation.